# App or apps like NetLimiter Monitor for Linux

Tags: linux, networking, software-rec, monitoring

I find [NetLimiter Monitor](http://www.netlimiter.com/download.php) quite handy on Windows **both** for the realtime per-process bandwidth monitoring and the recorded data usage.

[image]

[image]

What tools can I use to replicate this functionality in Linux?

I am okay using two separate apps for the bandwidth and the usage monitoring, but *the usage monitoring is a must have*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try "jnettop".
`sudo apt-get install jnettop` ([here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+source/jnettop)), and launch it with `sudo jnettop`.
(You can only view the usage. For limiting them, [Wondershaper, Trickle.](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/use-bandwidth-shapers-wondershaper-or-trickle-to-limit-internet-connection-speed.html))

For statistics (IE. log the data, total use) use [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) or [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/). (Maybe they are a bit of an overkill, but will do the job I guess.)